# Where should I ask a question about a programming interface for a game?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, off-topic

I wanted to ask about the documentation for the programming interface of the game [Vavio](https://peculiarcarrot.itch.io/vavio) since I can't find it anywhere. I first was about to ask on Gaming.SE, where I found similar questions that were closed as off-topic and recommended to be asked again on Super User. But I don't think it's on-topic on Super User either (or is it?).

Where should I post this question?

Comment: I don't think you can ask for it anywhere as it would probably been seen as a request for an off-site resource. (a so called recommendation question). There are a few cases where these obscure documentation requests get valued, positive received and kept around but chances that would work today are slim.

Comment: That said: you might have luck if you ask a good question about a problem you're trying to solve with that interface where answers might both solve your problem and provide either links or means to obtain that documentation.

Comment: @rene Okay, but on which site?

Comment: Maybe GameDev: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but check their meta first